The earnings of an employee follows the normal distribution $N(3000, 500)$. What is the probability that they earn more than $10 000$ in $3$ months?
Question :
The monthly earnings of an employee follows the normal distribution $N(3000, 500)$. What is the probability that this employee earns more than $10 000$ in $3$ months?

I've been thinking about this problem, but I can't seem to get anywhere with what I know about normal distributions.
How can I translate $N(3000, 500)$ monthly, into a distribution that can be used to find the required probability?
Clearly, in order for the probability to not be negligeable, the monthly earnings, over the next 3 months, would have to be somewhere between 1500 and 4500, i.e. 3 standard deviation apart. Is this knowledge enough to find any meaningful answer here?

In the notation you are using, is $500$ the variance or standard deviation of the normal?

@JulioPuerta  In $N(3000, 500)$, the value $500 $ is the standard deviation.

You have to assume the three months are independent, and find the distribution of the sum of three iidrvs

Assuming that the earnings from different months are independent, we have that the earnings over three months will follow a normal distribution $X\sim N(9000,\sqrt{750000})$.
This is because the normal distribution is reproductive, that is, if we have independent variables $X_i\sim N(\mu_i,\sigma_i)$ then $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\sim N\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \mu_i, \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma^2_i}\right)$.
Now, the probability can be easily computed: $$\Pr(X\geq 10000)=\Pr\left(\dfrac{X-9000}{\sqrt{750000}}\geq \dfrac{1000}{\sqrt{750000}}\right)=\Pr\left(Z\geq \dfrac{1000}{\sqrt{750000}}\right)$$
where $Z\sim N(0,1)$.
Using any software, such as R, we find that this probability is approximately equal to $0.124$.
